# Nvidia graphic card stopped working after kernel update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I have a computer with Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and a Nvidia RTX A4000

After suffering a lot to make these two work together (honestly not that much, I just had to install everything with the monitor connected to the card instead the integrated one, but until figure this out it was horrible) I managed to have a stable setup... until I got the notification of this update yesterday. The update passed to a new kernel, and right after restarting everything was broken. After grub I get a black screen now, but not a black screen as it could be still possible to open the command line, it's a black screen like the monitor is off.

The new kernel is the `5.14.0-1032-oem` and the previous one that worked is the `5.13.0-39-generic` one.

There are similar posts here and none of the solutions worked, mostly was from 5+ years ago, and even though there are comments there saying that worked with Ubuntu 20.04 unfortunately that is not the case for me.

The only thing I was able to do right now was setting the grub to initialize with the working kernel, but I'm pretty sure that this is not the best solution since I think with more updates and newer kernels, this one that worked will disappear... So that's why I come here to ask for some advice.

Any help is immensely appreciated.

The driver version that I am using for the moment is the `470.103.01` one. I have tried others but the result was the same unfortunately.

Comment: which nvidia version are you using? `nvidia-smi`should tell. Paste the answer into your question, **not** in a comment

Comment: Hello @kanehekili, sorry for the late reply, I just updated the question!